# Type 'org.sonarqube.gradle.SonarQubeTask' property 'pluginVersion' is private and annotated with @Internal

Tags: gradle, azure-devops, sonarqube, azure-pipelines

I try to configure code analyzing, using sonarcube on an azure pipeline.
When I run the pipeline I got errors like this.

Error: "Type 'org.sonarqube.gradle.SonarQubeTask' property 'pluginVersion' is private and annotated with @Internal."

```
Task:sonarqube FAILED
WARNING:API 'variant.getJavaCompile()' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'variant.getJavaCompileProvider()'.
It will be removed in version 7.0 of the Android Gradle plugin.
For more information, see https://d.android.com/r/tools/task-configuration-avoidance.
To determine what is calling variant.getJavaCompile(), use -Pandroid.debug.obsoleteApi=true on the command line to display more information.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem was found with the configuration of task ':sonarqube' (type 'SonarQubeTask').
  - Type 'org.sonarqube.gradle.SonarQubeTask' property 'pluginVersion' is private and annotated with @Internal.
    
    Reason: Annotations on private getters are ignored.
    
    Possible solutions:
      1. Make the getter public.
      2. Annotate the public version of the getter.
    
    Please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/7.0.2/userguide/validation_problems.html#private_getter_must_not_be_annotated for more details about this problem.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 8.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/7.0.2/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

BUILD FAILED in 6m 34s
78 actionable tasks: 78 executed
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add these lines on your .yml file:

```
task: Gradle@2
displayName: 'gradlew build'
inputs:
  (...)
  tasks: 'build'
  sonarQubeRunAnalysis: true
  sqGradlePluginVersionChoice: 'specify'
  sonarQubeGradlePluginVersion: '3.3'
```

Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/build/gradle?view=azure-devops

Answer (score 7):

At the time of making the build I encounter below issue.

**Type 'org.sonarqube.gradle.SonarQubeTask' property 'pluginVersion' is private and annotated with @Internal**

The above bug come when you are using latest version of gradle(7.x) and old version of sonarqube-gradle-plugin

To fix the bug please use 3.3 version **sonarqube-gradle-plugin**

*Please use below line at the project level build.gradle:*

classpath 'org.sonarsource.scanner.gradle:sonarqube-gradle-plugin:3.3'

Comment: What is the bug? Can you add reference link?

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.

Answer (score 2):

The "Code Analysis" comes from extension maintained by sonarqube, there is a [same query](https://community.sonarsource.com/t/sonarcloud-not-compatible-with-gradle-7/47613) on the community, you can comment and monitor on it.

In addition, you can try downgrade to Gradle 4.0 to check if it's a compatible issue.